# Computing 4 different arrays from a function

Tags: python, arrays, math

I'm trying to make a function that will compute this mathematical expression for each pass of n = 1, 2, 3 and 4.[The function is an approximation for the absolute value of x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3J5y.png). The goal is to plot the approximation for the different values of n, against the actual value of np.absolute.

So far I have tried this code, that yields all 4 different arrays together, which isn't very helpful for plotting:

```
x_values = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 101) 
n_values = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
y_values = [] 
 
def abs_approx(x, n): 
    s = 0  
    for n in n_values: 
        s = s + (np.cos((2*n-1)*x)/(2*n-1)**2) 
        value = np.pi/2 - (4/np.pi)*s 
        y_values.append(value) 
        n = n + 1 
    return y_values 
 
print(abs_approx(x_values, 4))
```

After this failed, I tried this code, which only yields the approximation for n = 4 but the array has the right dimensions, so I think I'm on the right track, but still can't figure out how to stop the loop from going all the way to 4, which I think is the problem.¨

```
x_values = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 101)
n_values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
#y_values = []

def abs_approx(x, n):
    s = 0 
    for n in n_values:
        s = s + (np.cos((2*n-1)*x)/(2*n-1)**2)
        value = np.pi/2 - (4/np.pi)*s
        y_values = np.array(value)
        #y_values.append(value)
        n = n + 1
    return y_values

print(abs_approx(x_values, 2))
print(len(abs_approx(x_values, 2)))
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the line `n = n + 1`? when you iterate with a `for` loop, n will increase every iteration without you having to do it manually

Comment: true, bad choice of example variable to use

Comment: Amended comment from above, now deleted due to confusing example used by me:

Also, when you do a for loop, your `n` will be independent of what is in your list. On the first iteration, `n = 0`, then `n = 1`, and so on until `n = i - 1` where `i` is the size of your loop (your `n_values` list in this instance). Here, your `n_values` are 1-4, so the output might look nearly correct, but you're actually doing `n = 0` to `n = 3`. To access the elements of your list, try `n_values[n]`.

Comment: @askman I still disagree with your comment, though. If `n_values` is a list, then `for n in n_values` will iterate with `n` successively taking the values in the list. If the list contains numbers 1,2,3,4, then `n` will take values 1,2,3,4, not 0,1,2,3.

Comment: so it will. consider me corrected

Comment: @Milena *"After this failed, ..."*  What makes you think this failed? What do you mean, "failed"? Was there an error message? Was the output not what you expected? What output did you expect and what output did you get?

Comment: The output wasn't what I expected: it was a list with 4 different arrays and I needed 4 separate arrays in order to plot them.

Comment: When I tried to plot it, there was an error message: x and y didn't have the right dimensions, because I was plotting x = linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 101) against a list with at least 4 times as much elements.